# How to access a current url of a magento cms pages which is created from admin panel?

Tags: cms, template-directive

http://magento.com/cms-page-identifier?a='jfls'&b='jhdgfjsd'

I want access a query parameter (a and b values from url) in a magento cms page. Can some body help me the {{}}  directives to print this value in cms pages.

Comment: where you want this values? like in which controller or in any particular page?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get URL parameters directly from the CMS page on the Magento editor, unless you use Javascript, which you **SHOULD NOT DO**, the best solution is the following (by steps):

1. Go to magento backend and edit the CMS page you want and put this code in its content: `<div>{{block type="core/template" template="geturl.phtml"}}</div>`
2. Open your FTP and go to the template folder of your theme (ex: /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/) and create a file named **geturl.phtml**
3. Inside this file you just created paste this code:

`<?php 
     $parameterA = $_GET["a"];
     $parameterB = $_GET["b"];
     echo $parameterA."<br>".$parameterB;
?>`

4. Visit your CMS page (http://magento.com/cms-page-identifier?a=jfls&b=jhdgfjsd) and view the result.

Let me know!